# Session variables not resetting

Tags: php, session

I'm having trouble resetting session variables in PHP. I'm now trying just testing resetting the session variable like this, but this doesn't even work:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["name"] =false;
if (!isset($_SESSION["name"])) {
  $message = getname(); //can't get this to ever be called
} else {
  $message = welcome();
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to unset the session variable

```
unset($_SESSION['name']);
```

Setting it to `false` makes it so it's still `set` (so `isset` will still return `true`), the only difference is that the actual value of the variable has changed to `false`.